Measuring the voltage in low voltage side of a mains powered device (that is non-isolated)
I have a task to measure voltage fluctuations provided from a non-isolated power supply. The voltage is around 3.3 volts but it fluctuates heavily.
The problem is that I need to be able to log these fluctuations using an external device like a Raspberry Pi, but it has to be powered separately in case of the device losing power.
Would using an isolated power supply solve my issue of powering the monitoring device if both grounds of the non-isolated power supply and isolated power supply are connected, or would it fry my monitoring device and/or isolated power supply?

Vout % load regulated error is due to the % Z (f) ratio due to ESR, ESL and loop gain. Source error is PSRR [dB]. Step load overshoot is a symptom of poor phase margin in the regulator.

How accurately must the logging reflect the actual voltage? Monotonically? With 0.1% error? 10% error? An analogue opto-coupler could isolate the measured voltage from  your measurement equipment, with a maybe acceptable error. A voltage to frequency oscillator driven from the measurement voltage could go through a digital opto, and could be counted by your RPi. Both much safer than making the RPi potentially 'hot'.

@D.A.S. that is probably the most unhelpful comment I have seen in a long time

@MCG The OP is getting bad readings and does not know why or where to look and how to fix. The answer is to find the cause.  Unhelpful is lack of intelligence to know how to use help.  Isolation will only remove ground loop errors and improve CMR which might not be the problem.  Maybe you should try to say something useful or tell me what you do not understand

Sounds like a job for a (battery powered) oscilloscope.

@D.A.S. I'm not saying I do not understand it. Look at the question. Look at what is being asked. Do you really think your comment is going to be of use to someone who needs to ask this question? The answer is no. Hence being the most unhelpful comment I have seen in a long time


Would using an isolated power supply solve my issue of powering the monitoring device if both grounds of the non-isolated power supply and isolated power supply are connected

If by "isolated supply" you mean the usual switching power supply block with the secondary side isolated from mains, then it won't hurt to connect the secondary back to mains.
The exception is if your power supply is earthed and internally connects Earth to the output ground. Then of course, you can't connect that to mains.
There are several other safety considerations. For example, if the supply is mounted in a metal enclosure which is connected to its output ground, then connecting that to mains will turn the supply enclosure into a safety hazard.
Then of course the Pi will be connected to the voltage it has to measure, not isolated from mains.
Thus the most convenient is to use wi-fi to send the data, because that's fully isolated. Logging to SD card means the SD will have to be extracted, so it will require a large red sticker "Whole board at mains voltage - unplug before touching". Of course, no keyboard, no screen, no accessible ports.
Personally, I would use a low power microcontroller, acquiring the measurement on ADC and sending the results via serial. Then, an isolated USB-RS232 interface or an USB isolator to connect it to the computer. This keeps the computer safe to use.
USB1.1 isolators are cheap and will power whatever is plugged in the USB port on the other side. There isn't much current available, but it is more than enough to supply a microcontroller board exposing a serial port via USB. Any Atmel-flavored Arduino would be a decent choice, as the ADC in these chips is pretty good if used with an accurate reference.
Isolated USB-RS232-RS485 interfaces also have an isolated DC-DC inside to power the electronics on the isolated side. Some keep it private, but others give you +5V and GND terminals, which can use that to power your microcontroller doing ADC duty.


Would using an isolated power supply solve my issue of powering the monitoring device if both grounds of the non-isolated power supply and isolated power supply are connected?

That could work. The big risk is that you connect a programming device or network to the Raspberry Pi and create a short to earth through that. This could cause a lot of damage.

You gave an interesting thought. Ethernet is a transformer isolated interface, it should officially handle something like 1000 VAC. I still would not recommend trying it though, for safety reasons.

Not me either!!

There's no guarantee that what you are calling "ground" is actually at a safe voltage level.
With that non-isolated power supply, plugging it in one way connects its "ground" to the neutral of the outlet.  If you plug it in the other way around, then the "ground" will be connected to the live wire in the outlet.  That puts everything in your supposed "safe" circuit (the Raspberry Pi and associated equipment) at line voltage.
Put simply, your Pi will be waiting to kill anyone and everything that touches it.
Besides killing you when you touch it, plugging in a USB cable to the Pi would kill any other line powered devices - like your PC.
You would need to guarantee that nothing and no one can ever touch or connect to the Pi while it is connected to your live circuit.

The safe way to do this is to get an isolation transformer.
You plug the transformer into the outlet, then plug the device into the transformer.
The reasoning is the same as for an oscilloscope.
Why on earth are o-scopes earth referenced?

"it has to be powered separately in case of the device losing power..... Would using an isolated power supply solve my issue ...?"
NO. This will only add SMPS CM noise to your measurement from both supplies connected by leakage to the ground and the grid unless you use differential measurement with a shield using the CM signal and ensure the bias is in the common mode range.
It does not need to be isolated, but it could be to avoid lightning ingress.  A large CM choke line filter acts as a CM LPFfor attenuating lightning impulses with CLC filter X-rated caps.
You do need a 0V reference for the ADC and the input must be biased in the CM range and not share ground current with the DUT (whatever you define as gnd = 0V) It could be a 1 Meg 10 uF LPF.
A cheaper solution with better noise and lightning immunity is to use a linear optocoupler.
https://www.vishay.com/docs/83708/appnote50.pdf
You could use a 1:1 transformer or good CM choke to pass the 3V to 0V to this as a breadboard near your ADC.  Then use X caps to ground to form the CM filter.

